# Twitter connector for Botium

Tags: testing, chatbot

Is there any support for twitter connected chat-bot for botium similar to Facebook(https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-fbpagereceiver)?

Comment: Currently, there is no twitter connector for Botium. Depending on the backend your chatbot is using (for example Dialogflow), there may be some options for using Botium on API level.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no Botium connector for Botium available. There are some chatbot backend systems supported (like dialogflow) which are occasionally used for developing Twitter chatbots, so maybe there is a Botium extension available matching your use case.
You can use the Botium Issue Tracker on Github to push a feature request.